# If-else shorthand syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can this code stub here below be written more like if-else shorthand syntax?

```
actual = ""
if fail_or_pass == 'FAIL':
    actual = "false"
else:
    actual = "true"
```

I was trying something like this, but it did not work

```
actual = ""
acutal = 'false' if fail_or_pass == 'FAIL' else actual = 'true'
```

Comment: What you mean is: `actual = 'false' if fail_or_pass=='FAIL' else 'true'`

Comment: `.. if ... else ...` is an expression producing a value. Remove the `actual =` from the right-hand side `else` branch, and correct your variable name (`acutal` is misspelled). `actual = 'false' if fail_or_pass == 'FAIL' else 'true'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inline `if` / `else` is an expression. It will evaluate to the first or third part depending on the second part. The assignment should happen to the left side only, not inside:

```
acutal = 'false' if fail_or_pass == 'FAIL' else 'true'
```

Also you don't have to initialize the variable before. And as an additional advise: Use `True` and `False` instead of strings to store boolean values, it makes everything easier and more consistent.

```
actual = fail_or_pass != 'FAIL'
```

Comment: Good point about the `true / false` strings, but I have to return them as strings unfortunately.